# How can you pull data within a method to an outer method for a Return call?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I know this is plaintext and not secure, but I am trying to learn how to make a login form with the WPF c# .net framework.  This is an inheritance issue, but I am not sure how to get the data from the database to the rest of the method on the bottom (which I commented out to show you what I am trying to do).

```
    private bool validateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if (UserName != "" & Password != "")
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "test";
            uid = "username";
            password = "password";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            // MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER;Initial Catalog=admin;Integrated Security=True"); 
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE username='" + UserName + "' AND password='" + Password + "'", con);
            /* in above line the program is selecting the whole data from table and the matching it with the user name and password provided by user. */
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                /* I have made a new page called home page. If the user is successfully authenticated then the form will be moved to the next form */
                User validatedUser = userList.FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserName.Equals(username) && user.Password.Equals(password));//I need this to be returned to the main method so I can make this work validateUser
                return validatedUser != null;//Here is the return that is being called for the main method validateUser
                MessageBox.Show("connected");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
            }

            // we need to try and get the database to this method
        //User validatedUser = userList.FirstOrDefault( user => user.UserName.Equals( username ) && user.Password.Equals( password ));
        //return validatedUser != null; //This is where it works, but doesn't pull from the processes above because of inheritance

    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to declare a variable outside the `if` block? Do that by declaring it there. If that's not what you're asking, please try to explain in more detail, because "get the database to this method" doesn't parse well for me. And what do you mean by "inheritance"? Are you declaring all of your local variables as class members? Why? Why would you do that?

Comment: So I have to place it as a string outside the if block.

Comment: It's checking the input strings then return them to the method if null then will make an error

Comment: "Place" *what* as a string outside the `if` block? What do you mean by "place"?

Comment: username and password, for the User validatedUser.  It goes to another class to use the User object.  I forgot some of the rules of pulling data outside an if statement.  Thanks

Comment: [Are you aware that `UserName` and `username` are two completely different variables?](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0535/6917/products/mistakesdemotivator.jpeg?v=1416776264)

Comment: Thank you.  I missed that!  That was my problem.  I was calling the database values and not the Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this was your issue:

```
private bool validateUser(string username, string password)
{
    if (UserName != "" & Password != "")
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "test";
        uid = "username";
        password = "password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        // MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER;Initial Catalog=admin;Integrated Security=True"); 
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE username='" + UserName + "' AND password='" + Password + "'", con);
        /* in above line the program is selecting the whole data from table and the matching it with the user name and password provided by user. */
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {

            MessageBox.Show("connected");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
        }

        // we need to try and get the database to this method
    User validatedUser = userList.FirstOrDefault( user => user.UserName.Equals( UserName ) && user.Password.Equals( Password ));
    return validatedUser != null; //This is where it works, but doesn't pull from the processes above because of inheritance

}
```

Comment: How about explaining what the issue was.

Comment: Whenever I pulled up the method it always came back null.  The validate user only shows certain icons for certain users as they type in their credentials.